# Arrays - Strings and Integer

Tags: arrays, vb.net

Can somebody help me with how to declare a 2D array which could carry a string and an integer?

I want to store values like

```
Name1 Roll Number1
Name2 Roll number2
```

Thank you both. It was quite a bit to digest. Although, I didn't understand the code, am excited to learn....I think it is worthwhile to share the big picture of what am trying to accomplish. I am sure you guys have a smarter way of executing it.. I have 2 text files which would carry Part numbers For instance. lets say

File 1:
PartA_Rev001
PartB_Rev001
PartD_Rev001
PartC_Rev001
PartC_Rev001

File2:
PartA_Rev002
PartB_Rev002
PartD_Rev002
PartC_Rev001

Finally, I need to print that 'In File 2, one instance of PartC_Rev001' is deleted'

To do this, I read the files into 2 one dim arrays. As a next step, I thought of and counting repitions for both the arrays and comparing them finally
seemed very cumbersome but could not think of a better logic !

Comment: Thank you both. It was quite a bit to digest. Although, I didn't understand the code, am excited to learn....I think it is worthwhile to share the big picture of what am trying to accomplish. I am sure you guys have a smarter way of executing it.. I have 2 text files which would carry Part numbers For instance. lets say

Comment: When someone posts an answer to your question and it works, you should click the checkmark next to it.  This moves it off the Unanswered list and it helps other users find good answers.  The [Tour] explains more.  Soon you will be able to upvote which is another way to help others.  As is, there are several questions of your like this one

Answer (score 0):

You could declare the array as `Object`.

```
Dim arr(0 to 10, 0 to 1) As Object
```

However you should not.
Instead declare a `Class` or a `Structure` with required fields and declare a 1D array of that.

```
Public Structure Data
    Public Name As String
    Public RollNumber As Integer
End Structure

Dim arr(0 To 10) As Data
```

Comment: Hi. can u pls let me know the syntax to add an item to this array - arr? Thanks

Comment: If you define `Data` as a `Structure`, you don't add items because they are already there as soon as you resize the array. If you define `Data` as a `Class`, you need to first instantiate each `arr(i) = New Data()` before you access e.g. `arr(i).Name`. If you [declare `arr` as a `List(Of Data)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36973627/11683), that would be much better.

Answer (score 0):

I love to use lists and custom classes. It's very much like GSerg's example but i find list's to be easier to manage and you can always derive an array from the list if needed.

```
Public Class MyCustomClass
    Private _Name1 as string
    Private _Roll1 as integer

    Property Name1() as string
    Get()
       if not isnothing(_Name1) then
          Return _Name1
       else
          Return "Nothing"
       End if
    End get
    Set(Value as string)
       _Name1 = value
    End Set
 Property Roll1() as integer
    Get() as integer
          Return _roll1
    End get
    Set(Value as integer)
       _Roll1 = value
    End Set

   sub new(RollersName1 as string, Rollvalue1 as integer)
      Name1 = Rollersname1
      Roll1 = Rollvalue1
   end sub
end class
```

Usage

```
Dim Rolls as new list(of MyCustomClass)
Rolls.add(new MyCustomClass("Henry", 6))
Rolls.add(new MyCustomClass("manny", 2))
Rolls.add(new MyCustomClass("Henry", 5))
Rolls.add(new MyCustomClass("manny", 2))
Rolls.add(new MyCustomClass("Henry", 1))
Rolls.add(new MyCustomClass("manny", 6))


for each R as MyCustomClass in Rolls

   Console.writeline("Player: " & R.Name1 & " Rolled a " & R.roll1.tostring())
next
```

Comment: Hello: can I know what the last part of the code does? I don't see a variable declaration for 'Name' and 'Roll1'                                                                                                    sub new(RollersName1 as string, Rollvalue1 as integer)
      Name = Rollersname1
      Roll1 = Rollvalue1
   end sub

Comment: Oh, sry, that's supposed to say name1. I'll fix it. Those are the properties Roll1 and Name1 which are declared as private _Roll1 and _Name1 in the begining of the class. Name1 and Roll1 are controlled proceedures for safely setting those variable values as is standard practice when creating a class.

Comment: Thank you again. I also modified my original question... Can u pls advise me on whether am complicating what I need to accomplish

Comment: Okay, sorry about the missing explanation. I will try to post an explanation and some links tomorrow night. Also I will take a second look at your goal and see if I can help. 
Am I understanding this correctly? You want to open 2 files and detect if the entries are not synchronized. Then you want to collect a list of the entries which occur more frequently in one file.